# Method to embed Cloud Page/Microsite into 3rd party website

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have created a signup form that would store the data into data extension and also in salesforce CRM. I want this login page to be embedded in our website. Is there any other way except for iframe that can be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using DEManager. DEManager can be used to get the data from your web Forms and create/update records in Data Extensions. DEManager gets your ClientId and data DataExtensionExternalid and update/create your record EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName in the given data extension.
Note:- insert your #clientId and #deexternalkey in the following code.

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="http://cl.exct.net/DEManager.aspx" name="subscribeForm" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_clientID" value="#clientId" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_deExternalKey" value="#deexternalkey" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_action" value="add/update" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_returnXML" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_successURL" value="http://example.com/Success" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_errorURL" value="http://example.com/Failed" />
        Email: <input type="text" name="EmailAddress"><br />
        First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName"><br />
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="LastName"><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Reference: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_demanager.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks it worked.

Comment: But I have an another issue, is it possible to do the embedded thing within marketing cloud only?
Because everytime if any modifications are required we have to ask that 3rd party developer to do the changes. Is there any workaround for that?